# Please review the problems below: Rails created post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I dont't know why but when i'm trying to create post, i got this error.
I created a scaffold "post"
Then i wanted to get my posts in a different controller, in my Controller home.

I put "belongs_to :home" in my Post.rb

In this step, all is fine.
But when i'm trying to create post, i got this "Please review the problems below:"

*Processing by PostsController#create as HTML                                                                                                                              Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0QgNSnhZWnsa+U9iYi1RB2Yk+qoW1be0Mj/o3579Es74oKBD452HQxZF144KBhR+in7UaSf9OLpzAyn8aJrB6A==", "post"=>{"title"=>"sfsf", "content"=>"sdfsfsfs", "author"=>"sdfsfsdf"}, "commit"=>"Create Post"}                                                                                                     (0.4ms)  BEGIN                                                                                                                                                          (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK                                                                                                                                                      Rendering posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application                                                                                                                 Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (14.6ms)                                                                                                         User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 2 ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1                                                              Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (6.8ms)                                                                                                                               Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.9ms)                                                                                                                             Completed 200 OK in 1512ms (Views: 381.2ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)*

post_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /posts
  # GET /posts.json
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  # GET /posts/1
  # GET /posts/1.json
  def show
    @posts
  end

  # GET /posts/new
  def new
    @post = Post.new
  end

  # GET /posts/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /posts
  # POST /posts.json
  def create
    @post = Post.new(post_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.save
        format.html {redirect_to @post, notice: 'Article crée.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :created, location: @post}
      else
        format.html {render :new}
        format.json {render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1
  # PATCH/PUT /posts/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @post.update(post_params)
        format.html {redirect_to @post, notice: 'Article édité.'}
        format.json {render :show, status: :ok, location: @post}
      else
        format.html {render :edit}
        format.json {render json: @post.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /posts/1
  # DELETE /posts/1.json
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to posts_url, notice: 'Article supprimé.'}
      format.json {head :no_content}
    end
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :author)
  end
end
```

post/new.html.erb

```
<div class="container left-box">
  <h1 class="left-box-title">Ajouter un article</h1>

  <%= simple_form_for @post, wrapper: :vertical_form do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input :title, label: 'Titre' %>
    <p>Contenu</p>
    <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'col-md-12 form-control content_post_create' %>
    <%= f.input :author, label: 'Auteur' %>
    <%= f.button :submit, class: "btn-primary", label: 'Mettre en ligne' %>
    <%= f.button :button, "Recommencer", type: "reset", class: "btn-outline-secondary" %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to "Retour à l'accueil", posts_path %>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no error specified in your console logs. Can you try `save!` instead of `save` in your create action? Since `save!` would return a more specific message of what went wrong.

Comment: You don't need an association to use a model in a controller with a different name. I don't really get how you could get to that conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error comes from `belongs_to :home` in Post.rb:

> The belongs_to association creates a one-to-one match with another
>   model. In database terms, this association says that this class
>   contains the foreign key. ([source](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference))

If you add the error full messages in your form like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for @post, wrapper: :vertical_form do |f| %>
  <ul>
    <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <li><%= message %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
  ...
<% end %>
```

you should see this error: `Home must exist`

To fix your issue you can remove the `belongs_to` association or, if `Home` is really a model, add the `home_id` to `@post` in your create action before saving.